# Specify Custom Application Context

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jersey-2.0

We are migrating some of our data services from Jersey 1.x using jersey-spring to Jersey 2.x using jersey-spring3.

We have a few test classes that inherit from JerseyTest. Some of these classes use custom applicationContext.xml files that are not specified in the web.xml file.

In Jersey 1.x the test classes that extended JerseyTest could call the super constructor with a WebappDescriptor.Builder to which a context parameter could be passed to set or override the application context path.

E.g.

```
public MyTestClassThatExtendsJerseyTest()
{
    super(new WebAppDescriptor.Builder("com.helloworld")
    .contextParam( "contextConfigLocation", "classpath:helloContext.xml")
    .servletClass(SpringServlet.class)
    .contextListenerClass(ContextLoaderListener.class)
    .requestListenerClass(RequestContextListener.class).build());
}
```

How can the same be achieved with Jersey 2.x?

I have combed through the [API docs](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html), [user guides](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/index.html) and some of the [sources](https://github.com/jersey/jersey) but was unable to find an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets assume your `Application` looks like:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    /**
     * Register JAX-RS application components.
     */
    public MyApplication () {
        // Register RequestContextFilter from Spring integration module. 
        register(RequestContextFilter.class);

        // Register JAX-RS root resource.
        register(JerseySpringResource.class);
    }
}
```

Your JAX-RS root resource like:

```
@Path("spring-hello")
public class JerseySpringResource {

    @Autowired
    private GreetingService greetingService;

    @Inject
    private DateTimeService timeService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getHello() {
        return String.format("%s: %s", timeService.getDateTime(), greetingService.greet("World"));
    }
}
```

And you have spring descriptor named `helloContext.xml` available directly from your class-path. Now you want to test your `getHello` resource method using Jersey Test Framework. You can write your test like:

```
public class JerseySpringResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        // Enable logging.
        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);

        // Create an instance of MyApplication ...
        return new MyApplication()
                // ... and pass "contextConfigLocation" property to Spring integration.
                .property("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:helloContext.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void testJerseyResource() {
        // Make a better test method than simply outputting the result.
        System.out.println(target("spring-hello").request().get(String.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: I spotted the `property` method in the API documentation but it was not clear to me that the method could be applied to the context parameters. I have updated my code according to your very informative example. From my output logs and tests it appears that the correct application context file is now being called. Thank you very much for your help. I have an additional question now on how to retrieve bean instances from the running config. Should I create a new question?

Comment: Well, if this question is answered then yes, create a new question. Thx.

Comment: Thank you. I have posted a follow on question. [Retrieve a managed bean from a JerseyTest container with jersey-spring3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282409/retrieve-a-managed-bean-from-a-jerseytest-container-with-jersey-spring3). I am linking it here as it may be beneficial for people reading this answer.

Answer (score 7):

This didn't work for me as I was not using the .xml style configuration, I was using `@Configuration` annotations.  So I had to directly provide the application context to the ResourceConfig class.

I defined the configure method in my JerseyTest like so:

```
@Override
protected Application configure() {
  ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig();

  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
  rc.property("contextConfig", ctx);
}
```

where SpringConfig.class is my class with the `@Configuration` annotation and 
importing `org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`